# Finding records where one attribute is greater than another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to find any product that has a higher `ip_solid` than `ip_liquid`.

I am trying to do the following:

```
Product.where("ip_solid > ?", :ip_liquid).count
```

However, it seems that `:ip_liquid` is not being read out from each object, and is probably evaluating to 0 or nil. Is something like this even possible?

Comment: `Product.where("ip_solid > ip_liquid").count` should do it as long as `ip_liquid` is a field in the database and not a method on your model

Comment: That worked, thanks.. maybe provide that answer? Sorry, I guess I never ran into that challenge before.

Comment: Nothing to sorry about. Happy coding!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Product.where("ip_solid > ip_liquid").count` should do it as long as `ip_liquid` is a field in the database and not a method on your model